# Django - Image scrolling functionality not working on localhost, but works perfectly on 127.0.0.1

Tags: html, django, image, templates, localhost

My case is this: I've got a Django website, and have implemented functionality to scroll through a list of photos using next- and previous arrow-buttons. This functionality works perfectly if I go to 127.0.0.1:8000, where it looks like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCcZR.jpg)
But on localhost:8000 this functionality does not work, and it looks like this: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpmDd.png)

The relevant template-code looks like this:

```
<div class="apartment-images">
        {% for image in apartment.apartmentimage_set.all %}
            <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="Apartment image" class="{% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
        {% endfor %}
        <div id="left-arrow" onclick="prevImage()"></div>
        <div id="right-arrow" onclick="nextImage()"></div>
        <div class="ellipses">
            {% for i in apartment.apartmentimage_set.all %}<div class="ellipse {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}"></div>{% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the javascript used to show the next and the previous image:

```
<script>
    let activeImageIndex = 0;
    let apartmentImages = $('.apartment-images img');
    let dots = $('.ellipse');

    function nextImage() {
        if (activeImageIndex < apartmentImages.length - 1) {
            activeImageIndex++;
        } else {
            activeImageIndex = 0;
        }
        changeImage(activeImageIndex);
    }
    function prevImage() {
        if (activeImageIndex > 0) {
            activeImageIndex--;
        } else {
            activeImageIndex = apartmentImages.length - 1;
        }
        changeImage(activeImageIndex);
    }
    function changeImage(index) {
        dots.removeClass('active');
        dots.eq(index).addClass('active');
        apartmentImages.removeClass('active');
        apartmentImages.eq(index).addClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

Now, as I've said, this functionality works on 127.0.0.1:8000 but not on localhost:8000 on the Google Chrome browser, and it works on both localhost:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8000 on Microsoft Edge browser. I've tried clearing the cookies for the localhost on Chrome.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix this!

I deleted all the buffered images and files in my chrome browser, and now it works on localhost as well :)

Here's how to do so:
https://7labs.io/tips-tricks/clear-site-specific-cookies-cache.html